# d3.js scatterplot with different colors and symbols - issues encountered

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to create a scatterplot of hundreds of datapoints, each with about 5 different attributes.
The data is loaded from a .csv as an array of objects, each of which looks like this:

`{hour: "02",yval: "63",foo: "33", goo:"0", bar:"1"},`

I want to display the scatterplot with the following attributes:

**Shape for `bar`:**

-circle to represent all points where `bar=0`, and a triangle-down to represent those where `bar=1` (this is a dummy variable).

**Color for `foo` and `goo`:**

- All points start as grey. `goo` is categorical with values [0,1,2] while `foo` is quantitative with a range from 0-50. *foo and goo are mutually exclusive, so only one of them has a value. In other words, for each data point either `foo=0` or `goo=0`.*
- Points with `goo=1` should be orange; points with `goo=2` should be red.
- `foo` should be mapped onto a linear color scale from light blue to dark blue, ie `d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 50]).range(["#87CEFF", "#0000FF"]);`

I can do each of these individually, but defining everything together is creating issues for me.

My code with reproducible data is here: http://jsfiddle.net/qy5ohw0x/3/

**Issues**

- For the symbol, i tried

`.append("svg:path")`

`.attr("d", d3.svg.symbol())`

which did not work. I tried a different approach altogether, but this did not map the values correctly:

```
var series = svg.selectAll("g.series") 
    .data(dataSet, function(d, i) { return d.bar; })
    .enter() 
    .append("svg:g")

series.selectAll("g.point")
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + d.hour +  "," + d.yval + ")"; })
    .attr("d", function(d,i, j) { return d3.svg.symbol().type(symbolType[j])(); })
    .attr("r", 2);
```

- For the `goo` colors (grey/orange/red), i mapped the values to the 3 colors manually:

First define `var colors = ["grey", "orange", "red"];`

Then while drawing the data points chain

`.style("fill", function (d) { return colors[d.type]; })`

This worked alone, but not with the different symbols.

- Finally, can i chain a second color .attr for `foo`? `d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 50]).range(["#87CEFF", "#0000FF"]);` would probably work if this is possible.

Again, the jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/qy5ohw0x/3/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do all the logic and comparisons in a `function(d)` for each attribute.

First set up some helpers:

```
// symbol generators
var symbolTypes = {
    "triangleDown": d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-down"),
    "circle": d3.svg.symbol().type("circle")
};

// colors for foo
var fooColors = d3.scale
    .linear()
    .domain([0, 50])
    .range(["#87CEFF", "#0000FF"]);
```

Then append a path for each symbol:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    // position it, can't use x/y on path, so translate it
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + (x(d.hour) + (Math.random() * 12 - 6)) + "," +  y(d.yval) + ")"; 
    })
    // assign d from our symbols
    .attr("d", function(d,i){
        if (d.bar === "0") // circle if bar === 0
            return symbolTypes.circle();
        else
            return symbolTypes.triangleDown();
    })
    // fill based on goo and foo
    .style("fill", function(d,i){
        if (d.goo !== "0"){
            if (d.goo === "1")
                return "red";
            else
                return "orange";
        }else{
            return fooColors(d.foo);
        }
    });
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qy5ohw0x/5/).

On a side note, I actually think straight `d3` is way more intuitive than `nvd3` for this situation.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I guess I had the right idea for appending a path element and then using `d3.svg.symbol()`, but my syntax was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's much simplier with nvd3.js

```
function prepareData (data) {
    return [{
        key:     'Group 1',
        values:  data.map(function (item) {
            item.shape = item.bar == "0" ? 'circle' : 'triangle-down';
            item.x = Number(item.hour);
            item.y = Number(item.yval);
            item.size = 0.1;
            item.disabled = Math.random() > 0.4;
            return item;
        })
    }]
}

nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
                .showDistX(false)    
                .showDistY(true)
                .showLegend(false)

  //Axis settings
  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('3.0f'));
  chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('3.0f'));

  d3.select('#chart svg')
      .datum(prepareData(dataSet))
      .call(chart)

  // A bit hacky but works
  var fooscale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 50]).range(["#87CEFF", "#0000FF"]);
  function colorer(d) {
      if (d.goo == '1')
          return 'orange';
      else if (d.goo == '2')
          return 'red';
      else if (d.goo == '0')
          return fooscale(d.foo);
      return 'gray';
  }
  d3.selectAll('.nv-point')
      .attr({
          'stroke': colorer,
          'fill':   colorer
      })


  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/qy5ohw0x/4/

PS Unfortunately Nvd3 lacks docs, so use it's github instead

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'll look into the nvd3 library! The jsfiddle doesn't seem to render the plot correctly, though. Did you test it somewhere else?

Comment: May be because i'm adjusted you x,y calculation and removed scale? It's for simplicity, you easily can bring that back.