# d3 svg symbol syntax

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to javascript and was trying to plot a scatterplot with multiple symbols. 
I came across this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573481/d3-js-scatterplot-with-different-colors-and-symbols-issues-encountered).

1. What's the difference between `symbolTypes['circle']` and
   `symbolTypes.circle()` in the solution below? The latter works while
   the former throws an error.
2. If "symbolTypes" is a dictionary, shouldn't we use `symbolTypes['circle']` ?

They use sort of a dictionary as a symbol generator in the accepted solution using

```
// symbol generators
var symbolTypes = {
    "triangleDown": d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-down"),
    "circle": d3.svg.symbol().type("circle")
};
```

Then in the later part of the solution the author uses:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
.data(dataSet)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("class", "dot")
// position it, can't use x/y on path, so translate it
.attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + (x(d.hour) + (Math.random() * 12 - 6)) + "," +  y(d.yval) + ")"; 
})
// assign d from our symbols
.attr("d", function(d,i){
    if (d.bar === "0") // circle if bar === 0
        return symbolTypes.circle();
    else
        return symbolTypes.triangleDown();
})
```

1. `symbolTypes['circle']` --> I get an error using this to bind circle symbol with my data using attr().
2. `symbolTypes.circle()` --> Using this, I can add circle as an
   attribute to the path element.

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3246928/5385381, particularly the answer from BenAlabaster

Comment: Try again with `symbolTypes['circle']()`

Comment: That did work. :) Thanks!

Comment: Great. Be sure to have a read of the linked question, as it will do a good job of explaining the difference between `symbolTypes.circle` and `symbolTypes.circle()`